# What does <?..?> mean in XML?

Tags: xml

What does `<?..?>` mean in XML?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
<test><?xml-multiple ?>
</test>
</tests>
```

I want to know what `<?xml-multiple ?>` means in the above XML? I syntax-checked this XML in **w3schools**, there is no error.

Comment: I don't know what `xml-multiple` does, but in general `<?` are XML Processing Instructions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a processing instruction. Processing instructions are used to directly pass on some information or instruction to the application via the parser, but without the parser actually interpreting it.

```
<?my-application some instructions ?>
```

The token after the initial question mark (here `my-application`) is called the target and identifies the application at which the instruction is aimed. What follows it is not further specified by XML, is treated by the parser as a black box, and it is up to the application to interpret it. Entity and character references are not recognized.

Processing instructions with the target `xml-multiple` seem to be commonly produced, accepted and recognized by applications that transform XML to JSON or JSON to XML (including Oracle) in order to identify arrays, even though I am not sure where and if its behavior is officially standardized.

Processing instructions are not to be confused with the initial `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, which is called a text declaration.

Comment: Seems a perverse choice of name, given that XML 1.0 states "Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.", and some parsers have been known to give warnings or even errors when names starting with "xml" are encountered.

Comment: Yes, I had the same thought as you, Mike. I could not identify where this convention on `xml-multiple` originates from and I could find this name mentioned nowhere on w3.org, which in my understanding should be the only one entitled to creating names beginning with xml.