# What does <! ... !> mean in XML?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, w3c

What does `<! ... !>` mean in XML?

This `<? ... ?>` specifies a processing instruction [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115398/what-does-mean-in-xml), but I found no information regarding the first one.

Comment: Check the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/ - Searching for `<!` you'll see that it is used for many different things. Comments, doctypes, entity definitions, conditional tags, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<! ... !>` is not an XML construct due to the ending `!>`.

However, the following XML constructs do begin with `<!`:

- `<!--` begins a [comment](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments), which ends with `-->`
- `<![CDATA[` begins a [CDATA section](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect), which ends with `]]>`
- `<![INCLUDE[` and `<![IGNORE[` begin [conditional sections](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-condition-sect), which end with `]]>`.
- `<!DOCTYPE` begins a [document type declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd).
- `<!ELEMENT` begins an [element type declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#elemdecls).
- `<!ATTLIST` begins an [attribute list declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#attdecls).
- `<!ENTITY` begins an [entity declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-entity-decl).
- `<!NOTATION` begins a [notation declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#Notations).

The ending of each of the above constructions is `>` unless otherwise mentioned.